# Get row numbers from duplicate rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, duplicates, rows

I need to read excel file and highlight duplicate rows, without editing excel or adding new column/rows. I read excel file with:
`df = pd.read_excel(path2, sheet_name='Sheet1')`
and with
`df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns.difference(['Mark 4']))`
i get all duplicate rows, excluding 'Mark 4'. Problem is that I can't extract those row numbers to use them with
`df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)`
to highlight those rows in excel since the are not included in the df.

I've tried
`dfToList = redovi['unique_row_to_index'].tolist()`
but since there's no unique row  I can't extract the data.

Output of `df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns.difference(['Mark 4']))` is:

```
    Type1 Type2
0    w    A
11    w    A
12    w    A
18    w    A
19    w    A
20    w    A
```

[6 rows x 170 columns]

I need to extract those row numbers which are not part of excel columns and use them as list for future formatting.

Comment: Do you want `df['Mark 4'].duplicated()`? This just a guess since you didn't provide your input data, only your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom function with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and `keep=False` for mask of duplicated rows by specified columns names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type1':['w'] * 3 + ['a'],
                   'Type2':['A'] * 3 + ['b'],
                   'Mark 4': range(4)})

print (df)
  Type1 Type2  Mark 4
0     w     A       0
1     w     A       1
2     w     A       2
3     a     b       3
```

Test:

```
print (df.duplicated(subset=df.columns.difference(['Mark 4']), keep=False))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
def highlight(x):
    c = 'background-color: red'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    m = x.duplicated(subset=x.columns.difference(['Mark 4']), keep=False)
    df1 = df1.mask(m, c)
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```